# What is the purpose of the second parameter to Array.removeValue in libgdx?

Tags: java, libgdx

I have been wondering what the second parameter of the method in Array removeValue does.

```
removeValue(T value, boolean identity)
```

What does indentify mean and should I pass true or false?

Comment: reading documentation is something you have to get used to: https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html

Answer (score 1):

From the [documentation](https://libgdx.badlogicgames.com/nightlies/docs/api/com/badlogic/gdx/utils/Array.html#removeValue-T-boolean-), which you should generally try to consult first:

> ```
> identity - If true, == comparison will be used. If false, .equals() comparison will be used.
> ```

If you pass `true`, `removeValue` will compare every array element to `value` with `==`. Otherwise it will call `element.equals(value)` to do the comparison.